# How to define and extends Expectations in JMockit?

Tags: java, unit-testing, jmockit

I recently started using JMockit. So far it's very nice. But I find myself writing something like this over and over.

```
@Test
public void testFoo() {
    new Expectations() {
        x.foo(); result = "1";   // expectation common to all test cases
        x.bar(); result = "2";   // varying expectation per each case
    }
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to define a common Expectations class, but extends/override it from each test case?

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes do things like:

```
protected void prepareHttpClientExpectations(@Mocked final Call call, @Mocked final Response response,
                                                 @Mocked final ResponseBody responseBody,
                                                 final String requestMethod, final boolean isSuccessfull,
                                                 final String body) throws IOException {
        new Expectations() {{
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            client.newCall(with(new Delegate<Request>() {
                boolean delegate(Request request) {
                    assertHttpRequest(request, requestMethod);
                    return true;
                }
            }));
            result = call;
            call.execute();
            result = response;
            response.isSuccessful();
            result = isSuccessfull;
            response.body();
            result = responseBody;
            responseBody.string();
            result = body;
        }};
    }
```

in order to reuse expectations. Then you just need to call the method with the desired values and ready to go ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can create non-final expectations and extend them.

See the [doc](http://javadox.com/org.jmockit/jmockit/1.16-beta3/mockit/Expectations.html):

> Rather than creating anonymous subclasses, we can also create named
>   subclasses to be reused in multiple tests. Some examples:

final expecation:

```
public final class MyReusableExpectations extends Expectations {    
    public MyReusableExpectations(...any parameters...) {       
        // expectations recorded here    
    } 
}
```

non-final expecation(which can be extended as base class):

```
public class ReusableBaseExpectations extends Expectations {
    protected ReusableBaseExpectations(...) {
        // expectations here
    }
}
```

test method:

```
@Test 
public void someTest(@Mocked final SomeType aMock, etc.) {

    // Record reusable expectations by instantiating a final "...Expectations" class.
    new MyReusableExpectations(123, "test", etc.);

    // Record and extend reusable expectations by instantiating a non-final base class.
    new ReusableBaseExpectations() {{
        // additional expectations
    }};
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but the doc you linked is different from the official one (I think?) [here](http://jmockit.github.io/api1x/mockit/Expectations.html). Is the one you linked the latest one?

Comment: @DanielYoon Sorry, it is 1.16 version. Not the latest one. I think you can have a try with it.